# PerformSeque from button

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

Currently I'm writing a iOS app with Xamarin.iOS and I wrote a custom UITabbarController named BaseTabbarController. In this ViewController I made a centered raised UIButton over the TabBar to achieve something like this: 
[image: RaisedCenterButton]

So this means that in my BaseTabbarController there is a onClick delegate for my button. When the button is pressed I would like to performSeque(push) to a  new ViewController. The following code gives me the error: "Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'searchSegue'. Push segues can only be used when the source conroller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController".

So what should I do right now? I'm not sure how to fix this..

My storyboard looks like this and I'm talking about the second row.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a push segue hooked up from your tab bar controller to the navigation controller on the second row -- that's not right. That should be a relationship segue (i.e. one of the tab bar controller's view controllers, a second tab).

**After Edit:**

To be able to push that controller from any other controller on screen, all the base controllers in each tab will have to be a navigation controller. As long as that's true, you should be able to do this. The basic procedure would be to find out which navigation controller's stack is onscreen (with the tab bar controller's selectedViewController method), and perform a push in code from that navigation controller,  using pushViewController:animated:. In the storyboard, you would want to have the controller you're pushing be disconnected from everything (no segues), and have an identifier, so you can get it from the storyboard to do the push.

Comment: I don't want that viewcontroller to be a tab, since it's going to be pushed when the center button is pressed. So how do I achieve this?

Comment: @Mittchel, pushed from where? What will be onscreen before the push?

Comment: Could be anything.. the user could be at any screen to be honest. So basically whenever the center button is pressed it should push that view.

Comment: @Mittchel, one more question. Are there going to be more tabs for this tab bar controller? Right now you show only one tab, if you add more will you need this controller to be pushed from any of those as well?

Comment: There are going to be more indeed. And yes, the UIViewController should be pushed from any UIViewController available in the application as long as the user pressed the Center button

Answer (score 2):

If the button which causes push segue is on tabbar then you an not perform push segue on it because tabbar controller is supposed to be a rootview controller and to have push segue your controller must have navigation controller as container.

For example MyViewController is controller for view A and OneMoreViewController is controller for view B now you want to call view B from view A then embed view A inside navigation controller

// Programmatically

MyViewController *vc= [MyViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *nav = [UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController: vc];

If you want to add that View A in tabbar then add nav object inside tabbar.

Now you can call viewB from view A using Push segue.

// and if your using storyboard then

Select the view which you want to embed inside navigationcontroller and choose Editor\Embed In\Navigation Controller from menu bar. that's it.

Comment: How am I able to push from every viewcontroller then?

Comment: If you want to call view A from view B then